# Changing a decimal format within the entire code using an option created in a switch menu

Tags: java, format, decimal

When writing the code, one of the tasks was to allow the user to change the decimal format within the entire program.

The program consists of multiple calculators, all of them should be able to give decimal results. The user has then a choice of how many decimal places they would like to see.

I know this can be done with format options just not sure how.

/Answer given already

Comment: And where is the code? Also what doesn't work?

Comment: Added now. I understand it's not amazing or very clear but I am just learning/ begginer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a variable containing a DecimalFormat

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
```

In menu option 4 where number of decimals is selected and read into `dec`

```
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(dec);
df.setMinimumFractionDigits(dec);
```

The above means that numbers will always be printed with `dec` number of decimals

Then whenever you want to print a double use the formatter

```
 System.out.println("The result is " + df.format(someValue));
```

An example

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    df.setMaximumFractionDigits(i);
    df.setMinimumFractionDigits(i);
    System.out.println("example " + df.format(24) + " " + df.format(12.3456));
}
```

outputs

> example 24 12
>   example 24.0 12.3
>   example 24.00 12.35
>   example 24.000 12.346

Comment: This works nearly perfect. This is fantastic. I was wondering though - is it possible for it to show 0's as well? As in. If the number is 24 it would show as 24.000. Not sure if I would use it but am rather curious if that would work.

Thank you

Comment: If you set both maximum and minimum to the same value it should always show that many digits.

Comment: How would I set that? My god, I am dumb. Sorry it's my 2nd week with Java :(

Comment: @PatrykSarnik I updated my answer with an example, I hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try java method: **String.format()**;

```
double number = 12.43544545;
int decimalPoint = 3;

System.out.println(String.format("%." + decimalPoint + "f", number));
```